# How to implement one controller mapping method for different scenarios

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-mvc

I have a spring controller method which could be called in different scenarios. here is the example...

```
@RequestMapping("/resetpassword")
public ModelAndView resetpassword( @Valid @ModelAttribute("resetpasswordForm") ResetPawdFormForm resetPawdFormForm, ModelAndView modelAndView){
```

... this method could be executed in 3 different scenarios....

1. using the hyper link coming from the user reset password link sent to user email..
   eg: localhost/myApp/login/resetpassword//
   Here I can authenticate userID and activationSecretCode in DB  and let user reset password
2. user can click on resetpassword link from user settings page.
   eg: Since the user is already coming from user settings page, I can validate userSession and allow him to reset password
3. User can login for first time successfully, but are forced to reset password due to admin requirements for reset initial default password.
   eg: in this user neither have session, nor passing any activationcode to validate.
   login method validates userid/default password and redirects to resetpassword mapping(method=GET).

**How can the system authenticate the user request and allow him to reset password?**

One alternative for this is, to use flash attributes and set a authenticationKey as flash attributes...which could be verified in resetpassword method.

is there other way to implement this....

Note: I posted an issue in implementing this approach in 
Post: **Spring: How to pass Java objects during redirect while using ModelAttribute**

Any help?

Comment: In step 3, you should authenticate the user on login (storing something in `HttpSession`). You can then redirect with a 302 to have them reset their user/password.

Comment: Storing flag in httpsession might work....that is what I am trying to do with redirectAttributes, but fails as I questioned in other post. Spring: How to pass Java objects during redirect while using ModelAttribute

Comment: What you are thinking about is flash attributes and they are implemented with the `HttpSession`. You can't use model attributes to pass attributes across request boundaries. You must use the `HttpSession`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to implement this is using three different action methods:

- resetPassword (e-mails)
- resetLoggedUserPassword (via settings)
- changeDefaultPassword

They may even share the same view, but the behaviors are not equal, so I would avoid overloading the action responsibility.

EDIT: elaborating on your comment:

1) To secure the e-mail link, one way is to add a authentication token. The token can be as weak as a hashed user id plus some salt string, or as strong as a GUID with expiration time in a database table, generated whenever a user requests a password reset.

2) The settings way is not a problem, considering that the user is already logged in.

3) The temporary password action can be secured the same way as 1, or the same way as 2, if you put the user on the session. Logging in the user even with the default password status shouldn't be a concern if the code that verify the status of the account are inside a request filter.

Comment: By dis-integrating in to three separate action methods, we are still not solving the problem of authenticating the user to change default password.  Since changeDefaultPassword is GET method, either request could come redirect from login action(as expected) or from hacker/ex-employee who knew my system well.  Previous comment, storing flag in httpsession might work....but still a problem as my previous comments...